# Replacing slider thumb with PNG?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, png

I'm trying to find a flexible cross-browser solution to implementing a png image as my range input's thumbnail, so I can turn it from this:

[image]

to this:
[image]

In chrome, the css tag "input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb" lets you select the thumbnail. How is this done in Safari, Firefox and other browsers? Is there a way to handle this elegantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari and Opera are webkit based like chrome so there it should work too.

For Firefox you can use:

```
::-moz-range-thumb
```

For IE 10+

```
::-ms-thumb
```

More information on brennaobrien's blog:

http://brennaobrien.com/blog/2014/05/style-input-type-range-in-every-browser.html